# Unable to Import 'turicreate' Module

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, turi-create

I installed 'turicreate' using the command `pip3 install turicreate`, but still I get the follwing error

```
import turicreate as tc
```

Error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-5e19a42750e5> in <module>
----> 1 import turicreate as tc

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'turicreate'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using python 3 kernel in the jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

If you are using anaconda (which you probably do on windows), it's very possible that you've installed it in the wrong environment.

You can install libraries directly from the notebook by running

`!pip install turicreate`

After that, running `!pip freeze` should show that library installed.

Comment: I am using ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

For `ubuntu 14.04 or above` use the following method.

First of all, we need some dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get install -y libstdc++6 python-setuptools
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

I recommend you to try these steps on virtualenv.

```
cd $YOUR_DIR
virtualenv venv
cd venv
source bin/activate
```

Now we successfully activated virtualenv. Then run the following commands.

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install turicreate
```

I hope it will fix your issue. Thanks!